# A (maybe) simple Hokuro puzzle

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction

Hokuro is a puzzle that was introduced to the Puzzling Stack Exchange on December 2nd, 2020 by sarsapilla as an entry for [Fortnightly Topic Challenge #44: Introduce a new grid deduction genre to the community](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7080/28179). It is a puzzle inspired by Kakuro, and it has similar rules.

Hokuro is a [grid-deduction](/questions/tagged/grid-deduction) puzzle with the following rules:

- Each cell contains one of the following symbols:
- [image]
- Each arrow indicates a step in that direction, while the dot indicates no movement.
- The clues in the black cells show the sum of the movements indicated by the symbols in the corresponding row/column.
- Symbols in consecutive white cells must be unique (a 'sum' cannot contain the same symbol more than twice)

In some cases it might come in handy to sneak a peek at the [Hokuro Cheat Sheet](https://bit.ly/hokurocs)

The puzzle (which hopefully has a unique solution):

[image]

<sub>Please give feedback as this is my first Hokuro puzzle that I've ever made</sub>

Comment: actually some of the clues need to be fixed/inserted to make this solvable (at all and with only one unique solution), the edit should take place a few minutes from now, sorry about that. edit 3 mins later: should be fixed now sorry about that.

Comment: Very cool that you created a hokuro puzzle as well! It seems to be missing clues in R8C3 and R5C7 though?

Comment: @sarsaparilla I will fix that in a bit

Comment: @Prim3numbah Can't access the page, is the content still available?

Comment: I deleted it, mistake. I'll post again.

Comment: I'll just write it. Is the dot, in the black square (row 2), a clue to the row on the left or the column below? If column, then the left-most cell of the row is unknown.

Comment: @Prim3numbah holy crap I am so sorry the dot is a clue to the row, for the hint for the column below there should be an arrow facing north, I will make some quick fixes.

Comment: No prob. I got stuck on that one so just wanted to check

Comment: Are [these clues](https://ibb.co/ydvwcBX) both correct? Or maybe some clue close to them? Because I seem to reach a contradiction on the row/column.

Comment: @Prim3numbah I will check that out in around an hour if that is fine (I don’t have access to a computer right now)

Comment: Ok, that's fine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149629/discussion-between-crsb0001-and-prim3numbah).

Comment: I imported this into Google Sheets for anyone who prefers to solve it this way: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YIIB65Hc2lhrFWrfIN3BYK5yP3YzR47YoupZ3VvLcu0/edit?usp=sharing It's the sheet titled "Maybe Simple Hokuro". One way to use it is to select File > Make a Copy in the menu bar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Step 1**

> I placed dots in single cells clued by no movement. 
>  [image]

**Step 2**

> I placed arrow in single cells clued by an arrow. 
>  [image]

**Step 3**

> Now after doing step 1 and 2, we can make some pretty straight forward deductions by first looking at the two clues marked in red, helping us filling in these red cells 
>  [image]

**Step 4**

> If we first focus on the clue marked in yellow, we can fill in these yellow cells. 
>  [image]

**Step 5**

> If we first focus on the clue marked in grey, we can fill in these grey cells. 
>  [image]

**Step 6**

> If we focus on the clue marked in blue, we see that one of the two cells marked in blue has to be a left arrow and one of them an up-left arrow. 
>  [image] 
>  If the top blue cell contain a left arrow then we'll reach a contradiction on this clue (where the blue arrow is pointing). 
>  [image] 
>  This means the top blue cell must contain an up-left arrow and the bottom blue cell must contain a left arrow. And the rest of the blue cells can be filled. 
>  [image]

**Step 7**

> To fill in these last bottom left 5 cells (marked in gold), I don' think there is a unique solution, but one arrangement that works is this: 
>  [image]

Comment: The clue marked in blue applies to the two cells to its right. The clue for the cells below is missing. There are indeed multiple solutions.

Comment: @DanielMathias Aah yes, didn't notice that