# A Hokuro, but with a twist!

Tags: logical-deduction, visual, grid-deduction, nonogram

Recently, I created [my first Hokuro puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/123116/a-maybe-simple-hokuro-puzzle), which was received really well. However, this time, there is a twist! Not with the rules or anything, however, it is combined with a Nonogram! Luckily, the sums of the movements indicated by the symbols in the corresponding row/column are already given. (except for one that can be easily deduced using [logic-deduction](/questions/tagged/logic-deduction))

Rules of Nonogram/Picross:

> The grid must be colored or left blank according to numbers at the side of the grid to reveal a hidden pixel art-like picture.

The rules of Hokuro:

> - Each cell contains each of the following cells:
> - [image]
> - Each arrow indicates a step in that direction, while the dot indicates no movement.
> - The clues in the black cells show the sum of the movements indicated by the symbols in the corresponding row/column.
> - Symbols in consecutive white cells must be unique (a 'sum' cannot contain the same symbol more than once)
>
> In some cases it might come in handy to sneak a peek at the [Hokuro Cheat Sheet](https://bit.ly/hokurocs).

The puzzle:

Nonogram/Picross:

[image]

[Play online!](http://www.landofcrispy.com/nonogrammer/nonogram.html?mode=play&puzzle=12%7C12%7C1x12,1x7.1x4,1x3.1x1.1x2,1x2.1x5.1x2,1x1.1x1.1x2.1x1,1x1.1x1.1x2.1x1,1x1.1x5.1x1.1x1,1x1.1x1.1x1.1x1.1x2,1x2.1x1.1x1.1x1,1x1.1x3.1x1.1x1,1x2.1x3.1x1.1x1,1x12%7C1x12,1x4.1x1.1x2,1x3.1x1.1x1.1x1,1x2.1x4.1x2,1x2.1x1.1x1.1x2,1x2.1x2.1x2.1x3,1x5.1x1.1x1.1x1,1x1.1x1.1x2.1x1,1x2.1x1.1x3.1x1,1x2.1x1.1x3,1x4.1x1.1x1,1x12%7Cx,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x&palette=white.grey.X,black..&msg=22448e5795a398b3ff1938f2a1f871dbbbcb6cfe544cd8bf685322443ac98e49)

For users who can't access images and don't want to do it online:

Rows:

```
R1:  12
R2:  7,4
R3:  3,1,2
R4:  2,5,2
R5:  1,1,2,1
R6:  1,1,2,1
R7:  1,5,1,1
R8:  1,1,1,1,2
R9:  2,1,1,1
R10: 1,3,1,1
R11: 2,3,1,1
R12: 12
```

Columns:

```
C1:  12
C2:  4,1,2
C3:  3,1,1,1
C4:  2,4,2
C5:  2,1,1,2
C6:  2,2,2,3
C7:  5,1,1,1
C8:  1,1,2,1
C9:  2,1,3,1
C10: 2,1,3
C11: 4,1,1
C12: 12
```

Hokuro:

[image]

<sub>*tried to transcribe in code block but was sadly unable to*</sub>

GLHF! (Good Luck Have Fun!)

Comment: For anyone who solved the Nonogram, I imported the Hokuro into Google Sheets for whoever prefers to solve it this way: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YIIB65Hc2lhrFWrfIN3BYK5yP3YzR47YoupZ3VvLcu0/edit?usp=sharing It is the sheet titled "Twist Hokuro". One way to use this is to select File > Make a Copy in the menu bar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved nonogram (black denotes filled cells, grey denotes empty ones):

> [image]

Hokuro with colourings included (grey denotes "black" cells this time, white denotes empty ones):

> [image]

Filling in single cells (btw I missed one in the upper right, which is included in the next image instead):

> [image]

Some more easy deductions, and one cell highlighted in red for the next deduction:

> [image]

That red cell is part of "down-right in 2" and "up-right in 2", so it must be either a dot or a right. It's next to a dot, so it must be a right. We continue:

> [image]

<s>(Note that the bottom left corner now **can't be filled uniquely**: there are two different options, as far as I can see.)</s> Sorry, I realised that this part can be solved uniquely, see the final image.

The green cell is part of "left in 2" and "up in 2", so it must be either a dot or an up-left. If it's an up-left, then the blue cell must be a right, the next one must be an up, the next one must be a down-right, contradiction. So the green cell is a dot, the blue cell is an up, the next one is a right, the next one is a dot, and we continue:

> [image]

As far as I can tell, the top right cells don't have a unique solution. We have **two different possibilities** for the overall solution, shown in blue/red in the following **final answer**:

> [image]